Weird syntax in MIT Statistic For Applications course
I'm new to statistics and I'm completely stuck on the first question from an online MIT course.
The full question is here (first question):
https://github.com/hoangnguyen7699/StatisticsForApplication_solution/blob/master/MIT18_650F16_PSet1.pdf
and an image of it is here: 1
My question is how should I read these equations?
$$
P[X_n=1/n] = 1-1/n^2
$$
$$
P[X_n=n] = 1/n^2
$$
$X_n$ is a vector of random variables where n is the number of samples taken, right?
So if n = 3:
$X_n = [X_1, X_2, X_3]$
So then I would expect that if n=1 then our equations would say
$$
P[X_1=1/1] = 1-1/1^2
$$
$$
P[X_1=1] = 1/1^2
$$
But this already gives us a contradiction? We have the a probability of 0% and 100% for a value of 1.
If we take n=2 then I assume our equations are:
$$
P[X_1=1/1] = 1-1/1^2
$$
$$
P[X_2=1/2] = 1-1/2^2
$$
$$
P[X_1=1] = 1/1^2
$$
$$
P[X_1=2] = 1/2^2
$$
but this also doesn't make sense.
My next attempt to understand this is to assume $X_n$ isn't a vector at all. So that n=2 would give us:
$$
P[X_2=1/2] = 1-1/2^2
$$
$$
P[X_2=2] = 1/2^2
$$
This actually makes sense because the probability sums to 1. But it seems insane to me that they would reuse the notation for vectors for something that isn't a vector.
Also this still gives us a contradiction for n=1 so it still seems to be broken.
Can anyone give me some understanding of what is going on here? It's been very demoralizing to be completely stumped so quickly

your first interpretation doesn't make any sense to me for several reasons - the second one is certainly correct (and the notation is not "insane", it's normal!). It doesn't matter if there's a problem with $X_1$ because they're only asking about limiting behaviour.

$X_n$ is not a vector, it is a real-valued random variable. We have a sequence of such random variables indexed by $n$, and this is standard. Your suggestion $X_3=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is circular so does not make sense. I think that document wants you to assume the index starts at $n=2$ so $1/n$ and $n$ are distinct. This is just a mistake in the problem statement

oh, that clears it up. Thanks for the help guys
